# Set CSS class from one page to another - WordPress, jQuery AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, jquery

In WP theme I have **post.php** (for single post item) and **blog.php** (for blog layout).
On single post, CSS classes are added to post div via jQuery (on click).

How to **get that classes** (strings)from single post (post.php) and use them in blog.php?

EG. Single post (post.php) print this html

```
<article class="single-post post-1">
<p>sometext</p>
<a>click</a>
</article>
<script>
jQuery("a").click(function(){
   jQuery("article").addClass("singleClass");
});
</script>
```

Blog posts (blog.php)

```
<article class="blog-post post-1">
<p>sometext</p>
</article>
<article class="blog-post post-2">
<p>sometext</p>
</article>
```

And also to get class from single post 1 and add it to blog post 1, post 2 to post 2, etc.
First time trying AJAX, so I'm not sure what to do. 
jQuery in post.php

```
var postClass = voteText+'-'+voteNumber; //some variables declared earlier
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax-class.php", //or /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php? This mean that data is posted to this file?
    data: { 'dataString': postClass },
    cache: false,
    success: function() {
        alert("Classes: "+postClass); // alert goes fine
    }
});
```

now I need to GET data from ajax-class.php?

```
<?php  echo 'Classes: '. $_POST['postClass']; ?>
```

This is not working.
If someone could just point me to right direction. Documentation and stuff.
Thanx

Comment: It should be `<?php  echo 'Classes: '. $_POST['dataString']; ?>`

Comment: I can't fully understand what you are trying to do, so I will ask first.... Does the alert box tiggers () at all? Just in case, in WP use admin-ajax.php it is recommended, also look up wp postnonce you will need this as well to create secure jq calls.

Comment: Thanx, I'll try this tomorrow, can't access site right now. If I use admin-ajax.php, does it mean that I can get data anywhere in my theme, via echo $_POST['dataString']? Alert box triger correct.

Comment: $_POST['dataString'] didn't worked either.  To simplify question: How to store jquery variable and echo it in function.php? Is this possible?